# C++ initialize all values of a member array for a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, initialization

In C++ how  initialize all values of a member array for a class?

```
#define MAX_MATRIX 20
Class Matrix {
public:   
         Matrix(); //constructor
protected:
         int n[MAX_MATRIX];   // note cannot do = { 0} or w/e here
};

Matrix::Matrix()
{
     // how to set all n to -1?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_MATRIX; ++i) n[i] = -1;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `std::fill`:

```
std::fill(begin(n), end(n), -1);
```

(These `begin` and `end` functions can be found in namespace `std` in C++11, or you can easily [implement them yourself](http://ideone.com/ruKX3) in C++03)

Comment: The problem doesn't even exist in C++11 ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This was a glaring shortcoming of C++03. In C++11 this has been fixed, and you can now initialize everything, including arrays:

```
class Matrix
{
public:   
     Matrix() : n { } { }
protected:
     static const unsigned int MAX_MATRIX = 20;
     int n[MAX_MATRIX];
};
```

(The nasty preprocessor macro is also not needed in C++.)

In C++03, you simply **cannot** initialize an array member, but you can **set** it to something meaningful in the constructor body, e.g. via `std::fill(n, n + MAX_MATRIX, 0);`.

(Of course it would be a lot nicer to say `std::array<int, MAX_MATRIX> n;`.)

Answer (score 2):

There's a type for this:

```
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix() : n() { n.fill(-1); }
protected:
    std::array<int, 20> n;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstring>
```

...

```
Matrix::Matrix()
{
 static bool init=false;
 static int n_init[MAX_MATRIX];
 if (!init){
   for(int i=0; i<MAX_MATRIX; i++){
    n_init[i] = -1;
   }
  init = true;
 }
 memcpy(n,n_init,MAX_MATRIX*sizeof(int));
}
```

The array `n_init` is initialized exactly once and stored in memory, then all subsequent constructions are a quick memory copy with no loops.  You should not see much decrease in speed if you increase the size of `MAX_MATRIX` as you would when looping through the index, particularly if you are calling `Matrix::Matrix()` many times.